# How to Login and Scrape Websites with Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I understand there are similar questions out there, however, I couldn't make this code to work out. Does anyone know how to login and scrape the data from this website?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'login':<USERNAME>, 
          'password':<PASSWORD>
         }

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post("https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/login", data=payload)

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
s = session.get('https://www.beeradvocate.com/place/list/?c_id=AR&s_id=0&brewery=Y')

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find('div', class_='titleBar')
print(soup)
```

Comment: What is the error/issue?

Answer (score 1):

The process is different for almost each site, the best way to know how to do it is to use your [browser's request inspector (firefox)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and look at how the site behaves when you try to login.

For your website, when you click the login button a post request is sent to `https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/login/login`, with a little bit of trial and error your should be able to replicate it.

Make sure you match the content-type and request headers (specifically cookies in case you need auth tokens).